# I can't know if a cookie exists

Tags: jquery, cookies, jquery-cookie

Here are my cookies in my browser history :

[image]

Here is my code :

```
alert($.cookie('mailID1'));
```

And i get 'Undefined'.

Could please explain why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cookies are only sent to the domain they were created from, so unless that code is running on `www.elevage-de-la-roche.fr` your code will never see the cookie.

Comment: OK i understand... I'm sorry for my ignoring... So I have to create this cookie on the same domain where i execute the jquery code. Thanks.